# String in union, segfault

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault, c++14, unions

This is basically a tagged union:

```
#include <string>
using std::string;

struct test{
    test():tag(INT),i(0){};
    test(const test&)=delete;
    test& operator=(const test&)=delete;
    enum {STRING,INT} tag;
    union {
        string s;
        int i;
    };
    test& operator=(string s){
        this->s=s;
        tag=STRING;
        return *this;
    }
    test& operator=(int i){
        this->i=i;
        tag=INT;
        return *this;
    }
    ~test(){
        if (tag==STRING)
            s.~string();
    }
};

int main(){
    test instance;
    instance="string";
    return 0;
}
```

It compiles but every time it crashes with a Segmentation fault. I'm just out of curiosity it's a pretty complete union class, provided a custom destructor, no move and no copy, then why will this crash? Must I use a `string*` in a union? If so, why?

Comment: Your `this->s=s` is not valid unless ``this->s` is already a valid string, which it may not be. You should use a placement `new`... but only if `tag==B`...

Comment: @rodrigo, you mean when `tag != B`. Only Then will an assignment be UB.

Comment: Unfortunately, you cannot use non-POD  types in a union. A fairly typical and simple workaround for this is to wrap the union in a struct, and move the non-POD instance to the struct.

Comment: @StoryTeller: I mean when `tag == B` you must use `operator=` but when `tag != B` you must use placement `new`.

Comment: @CherkesgillerTural, you can since c++11

Comment: @rodrigo, well I agree with that. And I think the tags need better names (sigh)

Comment: Story Teller, thank you for information, but copy the code to IDE and set c++11 but still it gives an error "illegal union member"

Comment: @rodrigo, Perfectly resolved, thanks.

Comment: @CherkesgillerTural, IDE aside, does your compiler support c++11? [Because gcc does, for instance](http://ideone.com/N5Dscx)

Comment: Yes absolutely I use Visual Studio 2013

Comment: @CherkesgillerTural, well it compiles on VS as well http://rextester.com/live/JYIP92960

Comment: Process exit code is not 0: -1073741819 in rexester.com :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Read carefully about the [rule of five](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_three_%28C%2B%2B_programming%29) in C++11

This is wrong code:

> ```
>  /// wrong code
>   test& operator=(string s){
>       this->s=s;
>       tag=STRING;
>       return *this;
>   }
> ```

because you are wrongly presuming that `this->s` is valid before assigning it. You should use a [placement new](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/new/operator_new) which *constructs* it (in an *uninitialized* memory zone starting at `&this->s`):

```
  test& operator=(string ss){
      if (tag==STRING) { s=ss; return *this; }
      new((void*)&s) std::string(ss);
      tag=STRING;
      return *this;
  }
```

BTW, I guess that you also should explicitly *define*

```
test(const test&s);
test(const std::string&);
test& operator=(const test&);
test(test&&s);
test& operator=(test&&);
```

BTW you are obviously missing the constructor:

```
test(const std::string&str) {
  tag = STRING;
  new ((void*)(&s)) std::string(str);
}
```

Comment: Is it safe to overwrite a it if it's previously a string?

Comment: Yes, but what is the relation with your question or with my answer? My answer is precisely to emphasize that `s` i.e. `this->s` is *not* yet a valid string

Comment: Yeah, I get your point, I'm just wondering if there's a if-statement needed in the `operator=`.

Comment: This is inefficient - if `tag == STRING` you can just assign and return. No need to destroy and then construct again.

Comment: Agreed. Will improve